# Ignore projects in GitHub workflow

Tags: github, building-github-actions

I have a solution with 5 projects all using dotnet5 except one (AZ functions) which uses dotnet3.1. My build action fails with `The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '3.1.0' was not found.`.

Is it possible to:

1. Set which project to build, or...
2. Have multiple solutions and select the solution to build, or...
3. Use multiple frameworks
4. ...or anything else to make it work...

Answer (score 2):

Turns out you can have multiple build frameworks :) :

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Set up .NET Core
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: '5.0.x'

    - name: Setup .NET Core 3.1 
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1 
      with: 
        dotnet-version: 3.1.x
```